# How does this Prolog program resolve to H=2? I don't understand the line of execution

Tags: prolog

I have the following chunk of Prolog taken from a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jdb7iF85LM&spfreload=10) on Prolog:

```
change(H, Q, D, N, P) :-
        member(H, [0, 1, 2]),
        member(Q, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
        member(D, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]),
        member(N, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]),

        S is 50*H + 25*Q + 10*D + 5*N,
        S =< 100,
        P is 100-S.
```

It's a program to make change on a dollar. H is half dollars, Q is quarters, D for dimes, N for nickels, P for pennies.

If I type `change(H, 0, 0, 0, 0).` as a query, it resolves to H=2. In the video, he mentions this is a program that makes change for $1, so I understand that two half dollars are $1, but I don't understand how it gets that.

My understanding of Prolog is that when I pass `change(H, 0, 0, 0, 0).`, it looks to find a value for H that will satisfy the conditions, so it goes to the first line and sees that 0 would work, then for the other "member" lines sees that the 0s that were passed also are correct.

It then sets S to a value, which given the above values would be S = 0. The next line makes sure it's less than or equal to 100, which 0 is, then sets P to 100-S (which is 100).

How is it not done there with H = 0? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`member(H,[0,1,2])` binds `H` to either 0, 1 or 2.  Since `Q`, `D`, `N` and `P` are all 0, the only value for `H` that will satisfy the equations at the bottom is 2.

When `H`=0, `S` will be 0, `100-S` will be 100, and since `P` is 0, `P is 100-S` will fail.

When `H`=1, `S` will be 50, `100-S` will be 50, and since `P` is 0, `P is 100-S` will fail.

When `H`=2, `S` will be 100, `100-S` will be 0, and since `P` is 0, `P is 100-S` will succeed.

Comment: Ah ha, I was thinking `is` to be a simple "equals" like in other programming languages, but it's more like a "must equal".

Comment: @DougSmith it's not quite a *must equal*, but it's an arithmetic evaluator. `is/2` requires a fully instantiated set of variables in the expression in its second argument, and unifies the variable in the first argument to that value. If it can unify, it succeeds. If it can't it fails. Just like any other Prolog call, it seeks to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the operational explanation, I would like to suggest CLP(FD) constraints for such problems, which are easier to understand and more declarative than lower-level arithmetic predicates. For example, in SICStus Prolog, YAP and SWI:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

change(H, Q, D, N, P) :-
        H in 0..2,
        Q in 0..4,
        D in 0..10,
        N in 0..20,

        S #= 50*H + 25*Q + 10*D + 5*N,
        S #=< 100,
        P #= 100-S.
```

Let us now reason declaratively:

If `H = 0`, as you ask, and the other parameters are `0`, as you specified, then what are admissible values of `P`?

```
?- change(0, 0, 0, 0, P).
P = 100.
```

From this, we see that if all other arguments are `0`, then the only valid solution for your query is `P = 100`. Thus, the goal `change(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` will certainly fail.

Comment: Other than a more concise way to express ranges, I fail to see how this is either easier to understand or using higher-level arithmetic.  You get those advantages for other problems, but I don't see them here.

Comment: The first huge advantage of CLP(FD) is their ease of use, especially for beginners: You do not have to consider instantiations with these constraints, so you can freely move the goals in the body. This declarative property in itself already justifies the use of constraints instead of lower-level arithmetic. A second nice advantage is the compactness of answers. For example, try the most general query `?- change(H, Q, D, N, P).` in both versions. OP's version gives you 292 solutions, and the CLP(FD) solution gives you a single determenistic answer that nicely characterises all solutions.

Comment: Third, as you already said, the CLP(FD) version is more concise and therefore also easier to read and understand. Fourth, it makes clear that all parameters are integers. You get a clean type error when you erroneously try for example `?- change(H, Q, D, N, l).`, whereas the other version just fails silently without letting you know that the argument does not have the right type at all. With such advantages, the question arises why beginners should be introduced to lower-level arithmetic at all this soon, and in my view, there is no reason to do that since it unnecessarily complicates things.

Comment: Sorry, but no.  1) For this problem, you use the exact same arithmetic as in the original; 2) if you say so; 3) if Prolog doesn't already have a range predicate, it would be easy to add one, and that is the only source of conciseness; 4) OP is perfectly clear that parameters are integers, although having a type check is nice.  Again, I'm not arguing against CLP(FD), just that this problem barely highlights its benefits.

Comment: 1) I *don't*. I use CLP(FD) constraints since they are easier to explain and use. 3) There already *is* a range predicate for integers, it is typically called `in/2` in Prolog systems that support CLP(FD) constraints (= all major implementations). 4) The greatest benefits are didactical: You only have to introduce CLP(FD) constraints to beginners instead of both low-level primitives *and* CLP(FD) constraints. They are easier to explain and use and do not have the procedural disadvantages of lower-level arithmetic predicates. I'm arguing against low-level predicates that are hard for beginners.

Comment: 1) So `#=`  &  `#=<` are somehow easier to explain than `is` & `=<`; got it (because those are the *only* differences in anything involving arithmetic); 3) this is conceding my point, no?; 4) for the third time, the miracles of CLP(FD) are mostly lost *on this problem*.